# jQuery - taking specific phrases from string

Tags: jquery

Examples of strings I have:

```
{"prices":"","sTld":"com","sSld":"test1","available":false,"type":"","options":""}
{"prices":"","sTld":"co.uk","sSld":"test2","available":false,"type":"","options":""}
{"prices":"","sTld":"in","sSld":"test3","available":false,"type":"","options":""}
{"prices":"","sTld":"lt","sSld":"test4","available":false,"type":"","options":""}
```

I want to extract these values:

```
com, co.uk, in, lt
test1, test2, test3, test4
```

In other words I want to extract every value from sTld that goes from ":" to " and values from sSld that goes from ":" to ".

I think I need to use regex for this, but I don't know how. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var obj=[{"prices":"","sTld":"com","sSld":"test1","available":false,"type":"","options":""},
{"prices":"","sTld":"co.uk","sSld":"test2","available":false,"type":"","options":""},
{"prices":"","sTld":"in","sSld":"test3","available":false,"type":"","options":""},
{"prices":"","sTld":"lt","sSld":"test4","available":false,"type":"","options":""}];
$.each(obj, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value.sTld);
    console.log(value.sSld);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skBm3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(json, function(index, value) {
    console.log(value.sTld);
    console.log(value.sSld);
});
```